# SELECT record based upon dates

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Assuming data such as the following:

```
  ID      EffDate            Rate
   1      12/12/2011         100
   1      01/01/2012         110
   1      02/01/2012         120
   2      01/01/2012          40
   2      02/01/2012          50
   3      01/01/2012          25
   3      03/01/2012          30
   3      05/01/2012          35
```

How would I find the rate for ID 2 as of 1/15/2012?
Or, the rate for ID 1 for 1/15/2012?

In other words, how do I do a query that finds the correct rate when the date falls between the EffDate for two records? (Rate should be for the date prior to the selected date).

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT Rate 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE ID = 1 AND EffDate = (
  SELECT MAX(EffDate) 
    FROM Table1 
   WHERE ID = 1 AND EffDate <= '2012-15-01');
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afe44/8) to play with. I assume here that 'ID/EffDate' pair is unique for all table (at least the opposite doesn't make sense).

Comment: Thanks for the SQL Fiddle tip as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Rate FROM the_table
WHERE ID=whatever AND EffDate <='whatever'
ORDER BY EffDate DESC
```

if I read you right.

(edited to suit my idea of ms-sql which I have no idea about).

Comment: `LIMIT` is proprietary MySQL syntax and not valid in SQL Server.

Comment: Is LIMIT a valid clause in MS-SQL?

Comment: No, LIMIT is not valid in SQL Server. `Msg 102: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.`

Comment: Thanks Aaron,I just saw your comment.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I haven't read the tag. No, it's not `mysql` specific, it's supported by many `sql` servers. I think in ms-sql it's something like `top`.

Comment: like `select top 1 rate from…`

Comment: +1 Should work too, and (I suppose) should be more efficient than my answer. )

Comment: I also think so, but didn't want to make a smart* comment to your answer ;-)